# model not refreshing inside ko.computed with Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

im using this modified example code to pull some data from twitter api and set the results to a viewModel

```
var myModel = new MyViewModel();
// Handler for .ready() called.
function MyViewModel(){

      this.show_search = ko.observable(true); // Message initially visible
      this.show_player = ko.observable(false);  // Message initially visible 

      this.tweetSearchKeyWord = ko.observable("google");
      this.currentTweets = ko.observableArray([]);

      this.showSearch = function(){

        this.show_search(true);
        this.show_player(false);
      };

      this.showPlayer  = function(){

        this.show_search(false);
        this.show_player(true);
      };
};

ko.computed(function () {
  $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23" +     myModel.tweetSearchKeyWord()+"&callback=?", function (data) {

      theData = data.results;
      myModel.currentTweets(theData);

  });
}, viewModel );


ko.applyBindings( myModel );
```

data is recieved fine, and data.results shows  Array[15]

but after i set it to the model with

```
myModel.currentTweets(theData);
```

myModel.currentTweets reflects as an empty array []

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Are you looking in the debugger? Look at `myModel.currentTweets()` instead

Answer (score 0):

There is no any need to use ko.computed because it works differently. What you need to do is just to specify any event handler and fill up the data there. Something like that:

somewhere in html:

```
<button data-bind="click:getData">Get</button>
```

in js:

```
function getData()
{
    $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23" +            myModel.tweetSearchKeyWord()+"&callback=?", function (data) {

      myModel.currentTweets(data.results);

  });
}
```

Or, if you want to update data after the definite time interval, use setTimeout() JavaScript function.